# How to apply cropping to a zoomed image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, crop, zooming

I wrote a class for image cropping. It works fine with non-zoomed images (images in original dimensions), but if I want to apply the cropping to a zoomed image, it goes totally wrong.

Here is the cropping class:

```
    var cropFlag = false; //false = disable cropping | true = enables cropping

function Cropper() {
    this.flag1X, this.flag1Y; //startpoint (upper left corner) for rectangle
    this.flag2X, this.flag2Y; //endpoint (lower right corner) for rectangle
    this.mouseDownFlag = false; // true, if mouse is pressed 
};

//gets the startposition of the rectangle
Cropper.prototype.handleMouseDown = function (e) {
    if (cropFlag) {
        var self = this;

        //start of the rectangle
        this.flag1X = e.clientX;
        this.flag1Y = e.clientY;

        this.mouseDownFlag = true;
    };
};

//gets the endpoint of the rectangle
Cropper.prototype.handleMouseMove = function (e) {
    var self = this;

    if (this.mouseDownFlag) {
        //end of the rectangle
        this.flag2X = e.clientX;
        this.flag2Y = e.clientY;

        //calculate the position to draw the moved and scaled image
        var imgDrawPositionX = (calcedPositionX * scale) + pointX;
        var imgDrawPositionY = (calcedPositionY * scale) + pointY;

        //redraw the image when rectangles size is changing to avoid multiple rectangles
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgDrawPositionX, imgDrawPositionY, width, height);

        //draw the rectangle shape
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = "5"; //thickness
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red"; //color
        ctx.rect(this.flag1X, this.flag1Y, this.flag2X - this.flag1X, this.flag2Y - this.flag1Y);
        ctx.stroke();

        var draw = function () {
            self.mouseDownFlag = false;

            //calculate length and height of the clipped image
            var clippedLength = width - (width - (self.flag2X - calcedPositionX) + (self.flag1X - calcedPositionX));
            var clippedHeight = height - (height - (self.flag2Y - calcedPositionY) + (self.flag1Y - calcedPositionY));
            console.log("clippedLength: " + clippedLength, "clippedHeight: " + clippedHeight);

            //calculate the start coordinates of the clipping image
            var startClippingX = self.flag1X - calcedPositionX;
            var startClippingY = self.flag1Y - calcedPositionY;
            console.log("startClippingX: " + startClippingX, "startClippingY: " + startClippingY);

            //calculate the coordinates to draw the image in the center of the canvas
            var centralDrawPosX = (canvas.width / 2) - (clippedLength / 2);
            var centralDrawPosY = (canvas.height / 2) - (clippedHeight / 2);
            console.log("centralDrawPosX: " + centralDrawPosX, "centralDrawPosY" + centralDrawPosY);

            //clear the canvas and draw the clipped image
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, startClippingX, startClippingY, clippedLength, clippedHeight, centralDrawPosX, centralDrawPosY, clippedLength, clippedHeight);

            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', draw);
        };
        //draws the rectangle and refreshs the whole canvas
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw);
    };
};

//initialize listeners and get button object
Cropper.prototype.initCropper = function () {
    var self = this;
    var button = document.getElementById('crop-button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function () { cropFlag = true; moveFlag = false; });
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) { self.handleMouseDown(e); });
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { self.handleMouseMove(e); });
};

var imageCropper = new Cropper();
```

Comment: see a demo here http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/ and the code is available here https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox but it usages jquery.